# Terminal in row mode : don't echo the tab

Tags: c, terminal

I'm doing a shell, and I want to add the auto-completion. For this purpose, I looked at `termios.h`.

I pass my terminal in canonical (= raw) mode like this :

```
struct termios settings;
tcgetattr(0, &settings);
settings.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
tcsetattr (0, TCSANOW, &settings);
```

After I handle the character like this :

```
 while((c = getchar()) != '\n') { 
    if(c == 127) { //backspace
        printf("\b \b\b \b\b \b");
        continue;
    }
    if(c == 9) { //tab
        printf("\b\b\b\b");
        //do something
    }
 }
```

My problem is that I don't manage to undo the echo of a tab, because it's not always the same number of spaces to remove and I have no idea of how I can do this. The best would be not to print the tab but I also have no idea of how to dos this...

So is there a simple way to not to print the tab? (Or if not, to undo it.)

Comment: You can disable echo: `settings.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO)` (while still disabling ICANON), and then manually output characters.

Comment: Ok,I thought of this but ok, seems not so bad, thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to undo those changes?

Comment: I had intended to return shortly to explain that I commented in lieu of an answer as I wasn't sure this was exactly what you wanted. It's good to store the current state of the terminal on startup with the `tcgetattr()` function similarly to how you obtained this structure in your code. Then, at the end of your program, restore those values with a call to `tcsetattr()`. Because code will not format intuitively in a comment, a writeup is [linked here](https://gist.github.com/polarysekt/c16a9318d49730eba14b).

Comment: Obviously the ideal case would catch any signals that could interrupt your program, and `atexit()` may be useful if you have multiple exit points. However, as is often the case while debugging, you may be left in a broken state. `$ stty sane` (from the command line) should restore common settings (NOTE: you'll probably be typing blind).